# Store Checkbox 'Checked' with localstorage for multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input, local-storage

I want to save my checkboxes to localstorage, but this code I am using would be too cumbersome for multiple checkboxes.... is there a better way to do this?

```
setStatus = document.getElementById('LineOp');
setStatus.onclick = function() {
    if(document.getElementById('LineOp').checked) {
        localStorage.setItem('LineOp', "true");
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('LineOp', "false");
    }
}


getStstus = localStorage.getItem('LineOp');
if (getStstus == "true") {
    alert("Welcome Back");
    document.getElementById("LineOp").checked = true;
} else {
    console.log("News");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way where you could put as many checkboxes as you want, just add the store attribute with a unique identifier for local storage. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2eS3/3/)

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    var box = boxes[i];
    if (box.hasAttribute("store")) {
        setupBox(box);
    }
}

function setupBox(box) {
    var storageId = box.getAttribute("store");
    var oldVal    = localStorage.getItem(storageId);
    box.checked = oldVal === "true" ? true : false;

    box.addEventListener("change", function() {
        localStorage.setItem(storageId, this.checked); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jQuery, try:

```
var getStstus = localStorage.getItem('LineOp');

if (getStstus === "true")
    $("#LineOp").prop("checked", true);

$("#LineOp").click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem('LineOp', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/VPC86/1/)